# Can't remove fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I can't remove fragment from fragmentTransaction. I want to remove fragment that I added in oncreate method. Below is my code :

```
fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            firstFragment = new FirstFragment();
            secondFragment = new SecondFragment();

            fragmentTransaction
                    .add(R.id.container_first, firstFragment)
                    .add(R.id.container_second, secondFragment)
                    .commit();


            VideoView video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

            video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://192.168.43.10/video.mp4"));
            video.start();


            Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "im here", 1500).show();



                    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();    

                        ft.remove(secondFragment);
                        ft.commit();
                }});
```

Comment: You said you can't, but what happens, is there an error?

Comment: @SimonMarquis I don't remember and i already solved problem, but there no was errors.